# Android preferences page divider removal / styling

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to figure out how to customise the dividers between items in my Android preferences screen. I basically want a grey line between every item (where by default the last item doesn't have one). This is my current setup. The greyline drawable works, and each item has its grey bottom line, except the default divider still exists, so every one but the bottom one has a double thickness line. How can I style / edit the default line between Item 1 and Item 2?

I have my pref_general.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Items"
    android:key="items">

    <Preference android:title="Item 1"
        android:layout="@layout/app_legal"
        android:key="legal"/>

    <Preference android:title="Item 2"
        android:layout="@layout/app_legal"
        android:key="legal2"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

I have app_legal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/greyline">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Politica sulla riservatezza"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```